# Classify all $3$-manifolds such that this map is injective

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

Is it possible to classify all the compact, connected and orientable $3$-manifolds $M$ with nonempty boundary such that the map $H_2(M, \partial M) \to H_1(\partial M)$, appearing in the long exact sequence of the pair $(M, \partial M)$, is injective? Obviously, a sufficient condition is that $H_2(M) = 0$, but can we describe the manifolds in the general case?

Comment: Look up the definition of exact sequence.

Comment: I know the definition.

Comment: What does the kernel of your map have to do with the image of the map behind it in the long exact sequence of the pair?

Comment: The map in question is injective iff the map $H_2(M) \to H_2(M, \partial M)$ is the zero map.

Comment: You can then use poincare duality to get more. But my guess is what you have is enough.